# How does the theorem 2 of algebra of limits contradict in this Q?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Q: $\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{15}-1}{x^{10}-1}$

Solution in my textbook using theorem 2 of algebra of limits I.e $\lim _{x \rightarrow a} \frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a}=n a^{n-1}$ .

$\begin{aligned} \lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{15}-1}{x^{10}-1} &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{15}-1}{x-1} \div \frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right] \\ &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{15}-1}{x-1}\right] \div \lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right] \\ &=15(1)^{14} \div 10(1)^{9} \text {} \\ &=15 \div 10=\frac{3}{2} \end{aligned}$

I agree with it using the formula but I also thought of thinking how would it be solved from the long way [Inserting x = 1]

We get :

$\frac{(1)^{15}-1}{1-1} \div\left[\frac{(1)^{10}-1}{1-1}\right]$
$\rightarrow \frac{0}{0} \div \frac{0}{0}=0$

My answer is completely different from the solution of my textbook. How is that possible ?

If anyone wants to argue that we cannot put value of x = 1 just like that. There is another example in my textbook according to which , we can.

In all of them , the Q simply says: Find the limit.

1)$\begin{aligned} \lim _{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{x^{2}-4}{x^{3}-4 x^{2}+4 x} &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x(x-2)^{2}} \\ &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{(x+2)}{x(x-2)}=\frac{2+2}{2(2-2)}=\frac{4}{0} \end{aligned}$

Here , x is tending to 2. This is a rational function.

EDIT: I will share a few more examples.

2. We have $\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{2}+1}{x+100}=\frac{1^{2}+1}{1+100}=\frac{2}{101}$
3. (iii) $\lim _{x \rightarrow-1}\left[1+x+x^{2}+\ldots+x^{10}\right]=1+(-1)+(-1)^{2}+\ldots+(-1)^{10}$

Comment: Your hint is correct: "we cannot put value of $x=1$ just like that".  The limit theorems in textbooks have *hypotheses* that must be satisfied.  Here, if we want to "put value $x=1$", they are not satisfied, so we cannot.

Comment: @GEdgar How can we prove putting x = 1 is wrong ?

Comment: I would suggest watching this complete video but this can also help you understand what is [infinitesimally small](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZ1Extuvcsw&t=90s)

Comment: @S.M.T it's not wrong it's just not the definition of limit $f(x=1)=\frac 00$ is right but the limit of $f(x\to1)=\frac 32$ Did limit ask you to find the $x=1?$ NO! it's $x\to1$ so why don't you try $x=0.9999999999999$ it tends to be $1$ is NOT $1$ I hope this will help you understand the very first step towards the amazing world of Calculus.

Comment: @DarshanP. K. Thanks , I will check it.

Comment: There is no such thing as 4/0.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes , correct but they did put x = 2. It matters in the end if the answer comes to be defined or not defined but the process , they used , says out x = 2.

Comment: @S.M.T Can you try to include an image? Or better, can you try to type the solution provided?

Comment: @soupless I have already typed the solution.

Comment: That's it? Ok, that's totally wrong. The one-sided limits are unbounded (informally, left-hand limit $=-\infty$, and right-hand limit $=+\infty$) which means the limit does not exist.

Comment: @S.M.T No, I'm only referring to the solution to the $x=2$ limit.

Comment: @soupless 2 more examples from my book.

Comment: @S.M.T You may want to accept an answer so that your question will be removed from the Unanswered tab.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you used, that is,

> \begin{aligned} \lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{15}-1}{x^{10}-1} &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{15}-1}{x-1} \div \frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right] \\ &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{15}-1}{x-1}\right] \div \lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left[\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right] \\ &=15(1)^{14} \div 10(1)^{9} \text {} \\ &=15 \div 10 \\ &=\frac{3}{2} \end{aligned}

is correct. But the part where you replaced $x$ with $1$ is wrong.

---

Why is it that some limits can be solved by replacing $x$ with $a$, but some cannot? This is because of continuity. That is, some functions are "good" that solving for the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ is the same as evaluating the function at $x = a$. These functions are:

- Polynomial functions, for all real $x$
- Rational functions, for all $x$ in the domain
- Radical functions, for all $x$ in the domain

  - For $\sqrt[n]{x}$ and odd $n$, $x$ can be any real number
  - For $\sqrt[n]{x}$ and even $n$, $x$ can be any nonnegative real number
- Trigonometric functions, for all $x$ in the domain

  - For $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, $x$ is a real number
  - For $\tan x$ and $\sec x$, $x$ is a real number and $\cos x \neq 0$.
  - For $\cot x$ and $\csc x$, $x$ is a real number and $\sin x \neq 0$.
- Exponential functions, for all real $x$
- Logarithmic functions, for all $x$ in the domain
- Any combination (addition, multiplication) of these functions

In summary, as long as the value of $a$ is in the domain of the function which is a combination of these through addition (including) and multiplication (including division, removing the zeroes of the denominator from the domain), we can substitute it.

---

Why is the limit not the same when I substituted $x = 1$ to $\frac{x^{15} - 1}{x^{10} - 1}$ and when $x$ approached $1$?

This is because $x = 1$ is **not** in the domain. You'll soon know what functions are "good" once continuity shows up.

---

See [this page](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/LimitsProperties.aspx#Cts_Fcns) for more information.

Comment: Why didn’t my textbook teach me that continuity earlier. I mean , it’s trouble like this.

Comment: Because continuity requires limits, hence limits are first taught. However, when teaching limits, to avoid confusion, "good" functions are used but will come to the point where methods to the "good" functions will be shown to not work in general.

Comment: A function is continuous if: (1) $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists; (2) $f(a)$ exists; and (3) $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$. This is why limits are first introduced. @S.M.T

Comment: So , in all the 3 examples I provided. We can use x = a ?

Comment: @S.M.T In the second and third example, yes. We can use $x = a$ as the values are in the domain. However, in the first example, we can't do that because $x = 1$ is removed from the domain. But because we can simplify things and still not affect the limit, DanielWainfleet's method can be used although we can drop the condition "If $x \neq 1$, then -".

Answer (score 0):

Let,
$$f(x) = \frac {x^{15}-1}{x^{10}-1}$$

Well, I agree with you! that the value of function $f(x = 1)$ is $ \frac {1^{15}-1}{1^{10}-1}$

But,
The value of limit of function $f(x)$ as $x \to 1$ is $\frac 32$

- Limit of function: This means you take the value of the function as $x\to a$ doesn't mean $x = a $ it means it's very very very close to $a$ it's never $a$
- Try this: $f(x = 0.99999) = \frac {(0.99999)^{15} - 1}{(0.99999)^{10} - 1} \approx \frac 32$

[image]

Comment: This can [help you for sure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZ1Extuvcsw&t=90s)
What is infinitesimally small?

Comment: I'll be glad to help you improve my answer if you still find difficulty understanding the limit.

Comment: I gave an example below of my Q. The textbook uses limit of function & puts x = 2. How is that correct to use then ?

Comment: @S.M.T About $x = 2$?
Here they mean that there is no other way to eliminate those ruining points because of which we won't be able to remove the ruining point from the numerator and denominator 

*Or else try* $x = 2 \pm \delta$ where $\delta \to 0$ like $0.000000000001$

Comment: @S.M.T see when you put $x = 1$ the answer comes to be $\frac 00$ but when you put $x = 2$ the answer came to be $\frac 40$ here they mean the answer format is not **zero over zero** $\frac 00$ that is what they tried to check if the answer is of format **zero over zero** also known as the indeterminant format $\frac 00$
Does this clear your doubt?

Comment: Thank u for being here but I’m still not getting it. Mostly because u see , I provided an example at last. There are similar examples like that too , not all of them with solution as 4/0. But all of them used the value in x that was given in the Q as tending to. & suddenly , in this Q , it says u can’t do that. So , I am having difficulty in understanding why is the previous one even true.

Comment: @S.M.T I'm disappointed that I couldn't help you. Enjoy:-)

Comment: Why do u say enjoy ? I have given 2 more examples. Maybe , they can help.

Comment: @S.M.T It just I'm sick today with a killing cold and my eyes are asking me to take a rest it just I was trying to visit and answer a few simple + short questions on MSE.
I need a damn rest!!!!

Comment: Oh sure , take care. Try putting something cold on eye for some time. It really helps

Comment: @S.M.T Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

$x^{15}-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{13}+x^{14}).$

$x^{10}-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+...+x^{8}+x^{9}).$

So if $x\ne 1$ then $$\frac {x^{15}-1}{x^{10}-1}=\frac {1+x+x^2+...+x^{13}+x^{14}}{1+x+x^2+...+x^{8}+x^{9}}$$ which obviously converges to $\frac {15}{10}$ as $x\to 1.$

Comment: Why did u write , “So if x is not equal to 1”

Comment: I wrote "If $x\ne 1$" because if $x=1$ then the RHS is a number and the LHS is $0/0$, which does not exist.